# How to set legend using d3.js and how to set different colors for multiline chart?

Tags: d3.js

```js
<style> /* set the CSS */
  
  .chart2 {
    font: 12px Arial;
  }
  
  path {
    stroke: steelblue;
    stroke-width: 2;
    fill: none;
  }
  
  .axis path,
  .axis line {
    fill: none;
    stroke: #808080;
    stroke-width: 1;
    shape-rendering: crispEdges;
  }
  circle{
    fill: blue;
  }
  .tick line{
    opacity: 0.2;
  }
  .domain{
    display:none;
  }
</style>
  <script src="d3.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    // Set the dimensions of the canvas / graph
    var margin = {
        top: 30,
        right: 120,
        bottom: 30,
        left: 50
      },
      width = 600 - margin.left - margin.right,
      height = 270 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

    var parseDate = d3.time.format("%Y-%m-%d").parse;
    //2015-06-20
    // Set the ranges
    var x = d3.time.scale().range([0, width]);
    var y = d3.scale.linear().range([height, 0]);

    // Define the axes
    var xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(x)
      .orient("bottom").ticks(5);

    var yAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(y)
      .orient("left").ticks(5).innerTickSize(-width)
    .outerTickSize(0)
    .tickPadding(10);;

    // Define the line 
    var priceline = d3.svg.line().interpolate("basis")
      .x(function(d) {
        console.log(d.T1);
        return x(d.T1);
      })
      .y(function(d) {
        return y(d.NATURE_QUERY);
      });

    // Adds the svg canvas
    var svg = d3.select(".chart2")
      .append("svg")
      .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
      .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
      .append("g")
      .attr("transform",
        "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

    

    // Get the data
    d3.csv("datahere2.csv", function(error, data) {
      data.forEach(function(d) {
        console.log(d.T1);
        d.T1 = parseDate(d.T1);
      });
      // Scale the range of the data
      x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) {
        return d.T1;
      }));
      y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) {
        return d.NATURE_QUERY;
      })]);

      // Nest the entries by symbol
      var dataNest = d3.nest()
        .key(function(d) {
          return d.CLOSING_DEPT;
        })
        .entries(data);
      console.log(dataNest);

      // Loop through each symbol / key
      dataNest.forEach(function(d) {
        svg.append("path")
          .attr("class", "line")
          .attr("d", priceline(d.values));
      });
      
      dataNest.forEach(function(d){
        var k = d.values
        var last = k[k.length -1];
        svg.append("circle")
        .attr("cx", function(d){return x(last.T1);})
        .attr("cy", function(d){return y(last.NATURE_QUERY);})
        .attr("r", 4);
        console.log(last)
        svg.append("text")
        .attr("x", function(){return x(last.T1) + 20;})
        .attr("y", function(){return y(last.NATURE_QUERY);})
        .text(function(){return last.NATURE_QUERY;})        
      })
      // Add the X Axis
      svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "x axis")
        .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
        .call(xAxis);

      // Add the Y Axis
      svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "y axis")
        .call(yAxis);

    });
  </script>
```

Hi everyone, Am new to D3.js so little bit difficult to understand the concept.
Help me to set legend above the chart and each line should be different color and according to that color the legend also should come... and the legend should come the colomn name as "CLOSING_DEPT"

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your code:

```
var uniqueNames = [];
            data.forEach(function(d) {
              uniqueNames.push(d3.keys(d).filter(function(key) {
                  return key !== "NATURE_QUERY" /*&& key !== "exclude everything except CLOSING_DEPT "*/;
                }));
              });
            uniqueNames = d3.set(d3.merge(uniqueNames)).values();

var legend = svg.selectAll(".legend")
                .data(uniqueNames.sort())
                .enter().append("g")
                .attr("class", "legend")
                .attr("transform", function(d, i) {
                  return "translate(0," + i * 20 + ")";
                });

              legend.append("rect")
                .attr("x", width - 18)
                .attr("width", 18)
                .attr("height", 4)
                .style("fill", function(d) {
                  return color(d);
                });

              legend.append("text")
                .attr("x", width - 24)
                .attr("y", 6)
                .attr("dy", ".35em")
                .style("text-anchor", "end")
                .text(function(d) {
                  return d;
                });

//uniqueNames is the filtered name unique set of each of the line in multiline chart(in your case CLOSING_DEPT).
```

For multicolours for multilines:

```
svg.append("path")
          .attr("class", "line")
          .attr("d", priceline(d.values)) .style("stroke", function(d) {
                  return color(d.name);
                });
```

Here is a working [example](http://jsbin.com/guguyu/edit?html,css,js,output) of the above code.Change data and filter logics as per your requirements.

Comment: Its not working can you please add the snippet here @siddP